# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat.error while installing ReviewBoard

Tags: python

iam trying to install ReviewBoard on my windows system.i got this error 
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat.please help

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Answer (score 1):

a) You need either a compiler, e.g. that bundled w/ MinGW, or
b) a pre-compiled executable for your OS and (ideally) Python version.

The latter might be tough to find, so if you go the former route it'll be roughly like this:

1. Download and install MinGW
2. Add `c:\MinGW\bin` to PATH environment variable (right-click My Computer...)
3. In `c:\Python27\Lib\distutils` create file called `distutils.cfg` and add the following:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```